# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to some random class in my app

Tags: java, android

I created an app and I store some data in a Firebase Firestore, everytime I want to fetch the data and display them in a RecyclerView I get this

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.****, PID: 9052
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.example.****.Models.Comments
        at com.example.****.Utils.CommentsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CommentsAdapter.java:43)
        at com.example.****.Utils.CommentsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CommentsAdapter.java:19)
....
```

I really don't know what I did wrong, can you please look over my code and tell me where I'm wrong?

Here's the Adapter:

```
public class CommentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentsAdapter.CommentsViewHolder> {

Context mContext;
List<Comments> mData;

    public CommentsAdapter(Context mContext, List<Comments> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CommentsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layout;
        layout = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_comments, parent, false);

        return new CommentsViewHolder(layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CommentsViewHolder holder, int i) {
        //bind data

        holder.title.setText(mData.get(i).getTitle());
        holder.content.setText(mData.get(i).getContent());
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(i).getPicUploadedBy()).into(holder.pictureProfile);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();

    }

    public class CommentsViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView content, title;
        ImageView pictureProfile;

        public CommentsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
            content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textContent);
            pictureProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileUser);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the activity where I use this:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
     mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("users-images");

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(user != null)
        {
            db.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("email", user.getEmail())
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: task.getResult()) {

                                           String fullname = documentSnapshot.get("fullname").toString();
                                           String address = documentSnapshot.get("address").toString();
                                           String city =  documentSnapshot.get("city").toString();
                                           String state =  documentSnapshot.get("state").toString();
                                           String country = documentSnapshot.get("country").toString();
                                           String phone = documentSnapshot.get("phone").toString();
                                           String zipcode = documentSnapshot.get("zipcode").toString();
                                           String type = documentSnapshot.get("type").toString();
                                           String rate = documentSnapshot.get("rate").toString();
                                           Boolean isActivated = documentSnapshot.getBoolean("isActivated");
                                           List<Card> cards= (List<Card>) documentSnapshot.get("cards");
                                           List<Comments> comments = (List<Comments>) documentSnapshot.get("comments");
                                           List<Documents> documents = (List<Documents>) documentSnapshot.get("documents");
                                           String profilePic = documentSnapshot.get("profilePic").toString();
                                           String email = documentSnapshot.get("email").toString();
                                           String password = documentSnapshot.get("password").toString();


                                           mUser = new User(
                                                   fullname,
                                                   address,
                                                   city,
                                                   state,
                                                   country,
                                                   phone,
                                                   zipcode,
                                                   type,
                                                   rate,
                                                   isActivated,
                                                   cards,
                                                   comments,
                                                   documents,
                                                   profilePic,
                                                   email,
                                                   password

                                           );

                                            myProfileDo(mUser);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });



  private void myProfileDo(User mUser) {
        List<Comments> commentsList = new ArrayList<>();
        fullnameView.setText(mUser.getFullname());
        addressView.setText(mUser.getAddress());
        rateView.setText(mUser.getRate());
        Glide.with(this).load(mUser.getProfilePic()).into(profilePic);

        for(int i = 0 ;i < mUser.getComments().size();i++) {
            commentsList.add(mUser.getComments().get(i));
        }


        commentsAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(this,commentsList);
        rvComments.setAdapter(commentsAdapter);
        rvComments.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



    }
        }
```

And The Model "Comments" :

```
public class Comments {

    public String uploadedBy;
    public String picUploadedBy;
    public String title;
    public String content;


    public Comments(String uploadedBy, String picUploadedBy, String title, String content) {
        this.uploadedBy = uploadedBy;
        this.picUploadedBy = picUploadedBy;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getUploadedBy() {
        return uploadedBy;
    }

    public void setUploadedBy(String uploadedBy) {
        this.uploadedBy = uploadedBy;
    }

    public String getPicUploadedBy() {
        return picUploadedBy;
    }

    public void setPicUploadedBy(String picUploadedBy) {
        this.picUploadedBy = picUploadedBy;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

The data is fetched well, if I println the "commentsList" it's not null, must be something on the adapter or the way I implement the adapter.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would try cleaning and rebuilding your project.  It looks like you're running a mixture of out-of-date class files and newer class files.  Normally, the compiler would catch this kind of error, so it's not clear how you got into this state.

Comment: I get the same error as before :(

Comment: What is the package (the top line) for your CommentsAdapter class?

Comment: package com.example.****.Utils;